# SSRS data comparison report on different dates

Tags: reporting-services

I am in the process of creating a report that will display sales for different date ranges.  What I mean is that the first column will display data for the date selected by the user.  The next column will display data for that date a week prior and the next one will display data for the previous year's.  The rows are grouped by stores.  What I have done is that I created a subreport which I call with the dates that I need by using the AddDate function.  My problem is that the report has become very slow.  My configuration seems to be good.  I was wondering if anyone has seen this type of situation before and might have some insight or if there might be an alternative way to create these type of reports.  Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure your Dataset Query shows the sales for all 3 date ranges, for example:

   SELECT
     StoreID,
     Date,
     Quantity
   FROM
     Sales
   WHERE Sales.Date (BETWEEN @UserDateFrom AND @UserDateTo) OR (>= DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()))

So this shows all Sales that are either between the dates selected by the user, or for the last year (which will also include the sales for the last week)

Then on your report add 3 Calculated Fields:

**SalesUserDates:**     `=IIF(Fields!Date.Value >= @UserDateFrom AND <= @UserDateTo, Fields!Quantity.Value, 0)`

**SalesLast7:**    `=IIF(Fields!Date.Value >= DateAdd(d,-7,Today()),Fields!Quantity.Value, 0)`

**SalesLast365:**    `=IIF(Fields!Date.Value >= DateAdd(d,-365,Today()),Fields!Quantity.Value, 0))`

So these basically say if the sale is within the date range then include it's quantity.

Then drag these 3 fields onto the tablix as your 3 columns

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply.  What do you mean by Change your Dataset to be filtered so that it encompass sales for all 3 Date Ranges?  Also, expressions do not allow me to have the sum function in them.  It complaints about having aggregate fields.

Comment: Hi, Sorry my explanation was not the best and I'm not an expert at this! I've tried editing my answer to make it more clearer, hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help.  What I ended up doing is that I created more datasets and I passed the date formulas as parameters to each of the datasets and then I used the lookup function to grab the values.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest one solution it will be helpful to create the report.

Create  the Query as below way.

select storied ,sum(CDQ),sum(WBQ),sum(YBQ)
From
(
SELECT Store ID,  Quantity CDQ,0 WBQ,0 YBQ 
FROM Sales WHERE Date=@Date

union all

SELECT Store ID,0  CDQ, Quantity WBQ,0 YBQ 
FROM Sales WHERE Date=DateAdd('d',-7,@Date)

union all

SELECT Store ID,0  CDQ, 0 WBQ,Quantity YBQ 
FROM Sales WHERE Date=DateAdd('y',-1,@Date)
)a
Group by storied

The above CDQ(current date Quantity),(WBQ(WEEK BACK Quantity)),(YBQ(year back Quantity))